# Substring alpha characters from an alpha numeric string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a file that contains employee numbers alongside the employee name and then the department. It looks like this:

0234569884566781DOE, JOHN K KF ("KF" is the department)

2487231227879636WHITE, ERIC C KF

0234569884566781DOE, JOHN KRT ("RT" is the department. Some do not have a space after the middle initial like the first two examples)

and so on.

**I am trying to do a substring where the output is the employees full name i.e. DOE, JOHN K.
How would I set up the substring to only get the full name and nothing else?**

The starting position will always be 16 because the employee number is always 16 digits. But I am not sure what the end position would be because the name obviously differs in length for each person.

Comment: Post the code that reads from that "file".

Comment: `.slice(16, -2)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```js
const staff = [
"0234569884566781DOE, JOHN K KF",
"2487231227879636WHITE, ERIC C KF",
"2487231227879636BLACK, JANE CRF"
];

const names = staff.map(line => {
  let n = line.substring(16);
  n = n.substring(0, n.length-2);
  return n.trim();
});

console.log(names);
```

Comment: @Bri if an answer resolves your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

```
const pieces = '2487231227879636WHITE, ERIC C KF'.split(' ')
pieces.pop() // remove department
const lastName = pieces[0].substr(16)
pieces.reverse()
pieces.pop() // remove first name with employee num prefix
const name = lastName + pieces.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little bit of regex to accomplish this:

```js
const employees = [
  "0234569884566781DOE, JOHN K KF",
  "2487231227879636WHITE, ERIC C KF",
  "2487231227879636BLACK, JANE CRF"
];
const regex = /^\d+([a-z, ]+?) ?[a-z]{2}$/i;
const names = employees.map(data => data.match(regex)[1]);
console.log(names);
```